# localStorage only use local variables?

Tags: variables, local-storage

Does localStorage only work with variables inside the listener? I can't understand what's the difference.

```
var _form = document.querySelector("#formMovies");

    _form.addEventListener('submit', ()=>{
        var title = document.querySelector("#addMovie").value;
        localStorage.setItem(title, title);
    });
```

It works!! But the next one doesn't

```
var _form = document.querySelector("#formMovies");
var title = document.querySelector("#addMovie").value;

    _form.addEventListener('submit', ()=>{
        localStorage.setItem(title, title);
    });
```

Comment: The difference is the point in time in which the `value` of `#addMovie` is looked up.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work in your second example is because your code checks the value of `#addMovie` when the page loads and stores it in `title`. Since the user hasn't inputted anything right as the page loads, `title` is set to undefined. It works in the first example because the value of `#addMovie` is being stored after the user is presumably done filling out the form.